# Expect in Perl not sending command on the server

Tags: perl, expect

I am new to expect. I am using `Expect.pm` to send some commands on the remote server. Script is doing telnet but not sending the command after matching prompt.

Below is the script:

```
use Expect;
use strict;
use warnings;
my $obj = new Expect;
$obj = Expect->spawn("telnet 47.134.117.133");
my $val =  $obj->expect(15, "<");
#print "****$val****";
sleep 5;
$obj->debug(1); # after a comment i modified this#
$obj->send("some command");
```

I tried printing the `val` and it is returning `1`.  But not sending command on the terminal. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

As per one comment I tried debugging command before sending command as `$obj->debug(1)`. It is giving output as

```
< Closing spawn id(5).
 at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/Expect.pm line 1386
        Expect::hard_close('Expect=GLOB(0x6002b0560)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/Expect.pm line 1575
        Expect::DESTROY('Expect=GLOB(0x6002b0560)') called at expect.txt line 0
        eval {...} called at expect.txt line 0
spawn id(5) closed.
Pid 968 of spawn id(5) terminated, Status: 0x01
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging using `$Expect::Exp_Internal = 1;` or `$Expect::Debug = 1;`?

Comment: Where can i type these

Comment: They turn on Expect's debugging output so you can see what is happening. See [the Expect docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect#How-can-I-find-out-what-Expect-is-doing).

Comment: It giving statement as "Closing .
 at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/Expect.pm line 1386
        Expect::hard_close('Expect=GLOB(0x600070438)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/Expect.pm line 1575
        Expect::DESTROY('Expect=GLOB(0x600070438)') called at expect.txt line 7
        eval {...} called at expect.txt line 7
 closed.
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the `some command` is, but you should send `"some command\n"` because telnet will not send your command until you press Enter. Also, if the `send` call is the last in your script (as in the example), it may exit before it sent it, so either put a `sleep` call after the last `send`, or close the expect properly with `soft_close`.